# Error: invalid expiresIn option for string payload

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set the expiresIn function in my javascript app. I am following the documentation, but I keep getting this error. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
app.get("/user", async (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.body;
  const accessToken = jsonwebtoken.sign( name, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, { expiresIn: 60 * 60});
  res.json({ accessToken: accessToken, name })
  console.log(accessToken, name)
})
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your payload needs to be an object otherwise it's treated as a string. Try this

```
const accessToken = jsonwebtoken.sign( {name: name}, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, { expiresIn: 60 * 60});
```